# Split a list into list of tuple with overlapping elements

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list  which looks like this:
`temp=[-39.5, -27.5, -15.5, -3.5, 8.5, 20.5, 32.5, 44.5, 56.5, 68.5, 80.5, 92.5,104.5]`

I want to split the list into list of tuple where second element becomes the first element of the tuple

e.g.: Expected output:
`temps = [(-39.5, -27.5), (-27.5,-15.5), (-15.5,-3.5), (-3.5,8.5), (8.5,20.5), (20.5,32.5), (32.5,44.5), (44.5,56.5), (56.5,68.5), (68.5,80.5), (80.5,92.5), (92.5,104.5)]`